# javascript popup box with onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am looking for the JavaScript code that can assist me in getting something similar to the button onclick event. Please take a look at the code below.

Javascript code

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function myPopup() {

    var overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
    $('.x').click(function() {
        $('.popup').hide();
        overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
        return false;
    });
    var obj = document.getElementsByClassName('clickLink');

    // alert("name");
    myScript = function() {
        overlay.show();
        overlay.appendTo(document.body);
        $('.popup').show();
        return false;
    };

    obj[0].addEventListener("click", myScript);

}
</script>
```

HTML Code

```
<div class='popup'>
    popup content here
</div>

<div id='container'>
    <button class='clickLink'>
        Click Here to See Popup!
    </button>
    <!-- this is working 5ne i called class in javascript -->

    <button type="submit" onclick='myPopup();'>
        Click Here to See Popup!
    </button>
    <!-- but developers need like onclick event -->

</div>

</body>
```

This popup script is working fine but I need an **onclick** event like button onClick='myfunction()'
please any one help me Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by 5ne?

Comment: provide us the fiddle please,as if this script is working fine then what else you need to work like? here you are using onclick function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to know how onclick event works in JavaScript, if that is the case as your question is not entirely clear, try something to the effect of the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click "Try it" to execute the displayDate() function.</p>

<button id="myBtn">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = displayDate;

function displayDate() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay,

Comment: Only a pleasure, let me know if this is what you were looking for and maybe mark as the correct answer if it worked :)

Comment: This was the only answer that solved my problem. SO SIMPLE! Simple can be powerful.